# How to draw line on google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have so many coordinates of a user from server and I want draw line to connect those like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPWYorS68WE).

I've tried to use [This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136203/how-to-draw-routs-between-two-locations-in-google-maps-ios-swift) but my app get crash, I guess this happend because i send too many request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The simplest way is to use a `GMSPolyline`.**

Assuming you have a `coordinates` array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`'s and they are in the correct order.

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
for coord in coordinates {
    path.add(coord)
}
let line = GMSPolyline(path: path)
line.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
line.strokeWidth = 3.0
line.map = self.map
```

Answer (score 0):

### - Swift 4 Extensions

Make path with coordinates:

```
extension GMSMutablePath {
    convenience init(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
        self.init()
        for coordinate in coordinates {
            add(coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```

Add path to map:

```
extension GMSMapView {
    func addPath(_ path: GMSPath, strokeColor: UIColor? = nil, strokeWidth: CGFloat? = nil, geodesic: Bool? = nil, spans: [GMSStyleSpan]? = nil) {
        let line = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        line.strokeColor = strokeColor ?? line.strokeColor
        line.strokeWidth = strokeWidth ?? line.strokeWidth
        line.geodesic = geodesic ?? line.geodesic
        line.spans = spans ?? line.spans
        line.map = self
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let path = GMSMutablePath(coordinates: [<#Coordinates#>])
mapView.addPath(path)
```